# jQuery - I get is 'price': price, but 'price' is a variable. Twig + jQuery

Tags: jquery, twig

There is my e-commerce code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var price = '{{ product.special ? product.special : product.price }}';
    price = price.replace('р.','');
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'ecommerce',
      'EE': 'ListView',
      'ecommerce': {
        'impressions': [{
          'id': '{{ product.sku }}',                 
          'name': '{{ product.name }}',
          'category': '{{ categoryDataLayer }}',
          'brand': '{{ product.brand }}',
          'price': price,
        }]
      }
    });
});
```

The output I get is

```
'price': price,
```

Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: debug and dump your variables, have you considered the string `price` is  stored inside `product.special`? Output both `product.special` and `product.price` to find out where the string is coming from

Comment: console.log("{{ product.price }}");
console.log(price);

output
1090р.
1090

Comment: And what about `product.special`?

Comment: Is empty in this case

Comment: "*The output I get is*" - Where do you get this output? The current code shown will not produce `price` with the provided information

Comment: In the browser console, I see the correct values, but when the page is rendered, the price is displayed as 'price'. Can I be sure that the data sent is correct and not Price ?

Comment: I see the confusion, `price` is a javascript variable, so it's correct you'll see `'price': price` in the rendered source, yes. The variable should contain the correct value, you can verify yourself by doing a `console.log(price)` before `dataLayer.push({...});`

Comment: This being said, you should still see the "correct" value in the rendered source where you initiate the variable, `var price= '<Here will be the rendered twig expression>'`;

Comment: And the problem is I can't see it in the render. But if you set price: {{ price }}, then the output will be correct